# How to set date format in input tag as ISO (2017-06-17T21:35:07.430Z)?

Tags: html, angular

I have an input tag like this:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="datepicker-date" id="start-date" name="start-date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" class ="form-control" formControlName = "startTime" data-date-format="">
```

What should be the date format I enter here to get the date like this:
data-date-format=

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Are you using angular 1.x ?

Comment: @Aravind I expect date to be like 2017-06-17T21:29:36.504Z

Comment: @MuhammadAlbarmawi No angular 4

Comment: @KirandeepKaur that format is not possible. what is your exact expectation? if you need more help or alternative way reach me out in fb @ aravind2109.

Comment: @KirandeepKaur you still face issues or it is solved?

Comment: @Aravind yes I converted it by using javascript date formatter - date.toISOString()

Comment: @KirandeepKaur Cool. :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using a bootstrap datepicker? The only formats supported are mentioned [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format). It looks like the format you want is not supported.

If you need this format elsewhere you can always just convert the Date object in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe that take your date as an input. and return
return new Date(your-date)